# Read google ngrams using google_ngram_downloader

Tags: python, nlp

I am using **google_ngram_downloader** to read the google datasets.

**Code :**

```
from google_ngram_downloader import readline_google_store
fname, url, records = next(readline_google_store(ngram_len=1))
for x in range(0,5):
    print next(records)
```

Here I am reading the datasets one by one **starting from 0,1,... a,b,c.. z**. **next(readline_google_store(ngram_len=1))** gives the ngrams one by one. I want to read directly the datasets which will **'a','b'** anything not one by one.

**Required**: Read only dataset which starts from letter **'a'** having **1-gram** dataset.

Comment: I am confused. What is the question?

Comment: `@Daniel` : Google is stored its n-gram in this format, given http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html and above code is used to read these n-grams sequentially. What I want that suppose I want to read only dataset having **letter 'a' of 5-grams** and skip the remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add the `indices` explicitly. Use this line to get just the ngrams of length 1 that start with **a**.

```
fname, url, records = next(readline_google_store(ngram_len=1,indices='a'))
```